# How to push data to clients from a SignalR hub in C#

Tags: c#, stream, signalr

I am using the code from the MS sample:

```
        public Task PushMessage(string Message)
        {
            var T = Clients.All.SendAsync(Message);
            Console.WriteLine("I'm here");
            return T;
        }
```

but the writeline call is never reached. So do I need to check that at least one client is connected before pushing messages?

what I am trying to achieve is the following: I have a lot of small messages being produced that need to be pushed to the clients connected to the hub, if any.
so the messages are produced no matter what and if clients are connected, they should receive it.

right now, I've put a SendMessage call in the event that is generated when new data is being built, but this just results in the callback being held because SendMessage doesn't return.

the behavior I am looking for is: if there are clients, they get the message, if there are no clients, the message is discarded.

how can I achieve this?

I think I may be misunderstanding how SignalR works and I would really like to find an example C# <-> C# because every single example on the web is web/js centric.

Comment: You can always use Clients.All.SendAsync(Message).Result if you wish to see the return value of the SendAsync. Also i believe you should check async and await.

Comment: I don’t want to see the result, I want to send, or kill if there is no client connected. Instead it stays hanging until a timeout when there is no client

Answer (score 0):

Walk through some of the sample code for console applications in their [GitHub](https://github.com/SignalR/Samples).

SignalR will only broadcast if there are connections to be broadcast to. That's part of the point of this, so you don't have to manage that aspect. You can certainly poll for data or get it however you like, but when you tell it to send SignalR will check to see if there is anyone to send it to.

As far as the C# to C# vs C# to web/js, yes, you are thinking about that wrong. If it's a console app or web/js it's a client. The communication is client to server and server(hub) to client. It does not matter if it is a console app or web/js or any other type of client.

Here's a sample of a console app I use for demo purposes that allows me to chat back and forth between console and a web page or web page to console through the hub:

```
        private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {

            var connection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:7132/");
            IHubProxy hub = connection.CreateHubProxy("ChatHub");

            hub.On<string, string>("broadcastMessage", (name, message) => { Console.Write(name + ": "); Console.WriteLine(message); });
            connection.Start().Wait();
            hub.Invoke("Notify", "Console app", connection.ConnectionId);
            string msg = null;

            while ((msg = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                hub.Invoke("Send", "Console app", msg).Wait();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error" + e.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: I know it doesn’t matter what type of client is there, but all client samples are in JS :) I haven’t found a single one in C#. The issue I have is that when there is no client, my broadcast call doesn’t return before a timeout; I don’t want a result but I don’t want it to hold the thread as I have 20-30 messages per sec to send to the clients. It for an internal app with around 3 clients connected at the same time. I would like to know how to just kill the message if there is no client, I can’t have thousands of messages queuing waiting for a timeout

Comment: Maybe provide more code?  this again is from my sample in the hub and the only thing I need to send back and forth:  public void Send(string name, string message)
        {
            // Call the broadcastMessage method to update clients.
            Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
        }

Comment: I just noticed your other questions are tagged with Signal-Core, where as this is just signalr (meaning .NET, not .NETCORE). Please be aware my answers are in regards to .NET version. A sample console app for .NETCORE can be found here: https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/blob/master/samples/ClientSample/Program.cs

Comment: ah, yes, the API doesn't look the same since I create a class that derives from hub, register the path with asp.net and the rest is taken care of; there is no handling of the connection